# Constants Depending on the Location Counter

Tags: assembly, zos

I want to ask about defining constant using location counter (LC) in assembly on IBM z/OS

---

Here some example so you can understand what i mean

```
DOWNTBL   DC       32AL1(DOWNTBL+31-*)
```

It will generate automaticly 1F,1E,1D,1C,..,00

```
SQRS      DC       40Y((*-SQRS+2)*(*-SQRS+2)/4)
```

It will generate 1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2,...,40^2

---

Can anyone help me how to define (10^0 until 10^10), using Constants Depending on the Location Counter.

Comment: HLASM does not have a power operator for expressions. However, what you ask could be done using conditional assembly in a loop; are you familiar with that?

Comment: If I'm doing my math correctly, 10^10 is 10 billion, so these values won't fit in a standard 32-bit calculation. From the IBM HLASM Language Reference: "Note: It is important to remember that expression evaluation for address constants is restricted to using 32 bit internal arithmetic. "